# Checking if a particular OWL axiom is consistent (i.e. no contradictory knowledge exists) or not?

Tags: java, owl, ontology, consistency, owl-api

I am currently using the Hermit OWL reasoner for checking consistency within a given ontology and it works fine.

*I understand that, with an inconsistent ontology OWL reasoners cannot infer any useful information and its a severe error.*

What I was looking for: Is there a method by which I could ask the reasoner to check if a particular axiom "A/B" is inconsistent or not?.

```
    import org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner;
    import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
    import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
    import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass;
    import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
    import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;
    import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.Node;

    /**
     * This example demonstrates how HermiT can be used to check the consistency of the Pizza ontology
     */
    public class ConsistencyChecker {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            // First, we create an OWLOntologyManager object. The manager will load and save ontologies.
            OWLOntologyManager m=OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
            // We use the OWL API to load the Pizza ontology.
            OWLOntology o=m.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(IRI.create("http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/isg/ontologies/UID/00793.owl"));
            // Now, we instantiate HermiT by creating an instance of the Reasoner class in the package org.semanticweb.HermiT.
            Reasoner hermit=new Reasoner(o);
            // Finally, we output whether the ontology is consistent.
            System.out.println(hermit.isConsistent());

//------
                Node<OWLClass> unsatisfiableClasses = hermit.getUnsatisfiableClasses();
                for (OWLClass owlClass : unsatisfiableClasses) {
                    System.out.println(owlClass.getIRI());
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: An axiom is not inconsistent by itself, unless it is of the form "X instance of owl:Nothing". There are libraries to find explanations on why an ontology is inconsistent, see for example https://github.com/matthewhorridge/owlexplanation

Comment: Yes, @Ignazio's point is important.  Very few axioms will be inconsistent on their own. Typically it's a *combination* of axioms that is inconsistent.  E.g., where *a* and *b* are numbers, each of *a < b* and *b < a* is satisfiable alone, but the *combination* is inconsistent.  You might be interested in checking whether each axiom in the ontology makes the ontology inconsistent if the ontology without A is consistent.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor and Ignazio, Yes I agree with your comments. As a follow up question, Ive made some changes to the code to point out inconsistencies as a whole. Is it possible to obtain explanations for such inconsistencies something like [this](https://github.com/phillord/hermit-maven/blob/master/examples/org/semanticweb/HermiT/examples/Explanations.java)?. If so, what additions should I make to my existing code to accomodate it.

Comment: The owlexplanation project I linked above is able to provide explanations for both inconsistencies and unsatisfiability. There are a few examples available in its documentation but I have little experience using it.